# How to display values from a related entity in combobox?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I have a model with following entities:
USERS
(LINK (primary key), DEP_LINK (link to DEPARTMENTS), ....)
DEPARTMENTS
(LINK, TITLE, ....)
I want to implement a Login window and I need to display all users in ComboBox. My ComboBox looks like this:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" Margin="66,87,65,0" Name="cmbUsername" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}" ItemsSource="{Binding Usernames}" 
DisplayMemberPath="LINK"/>
```

My ViewModel looks like this:

```
private RSDBEntities dataContext;

public USERS SelectedUser { get; set; }

public List<USERS> Usernames { get; set; }

public AuthorizationViewModel()
{
    dataContext = new RSDBEntities();
    Users = new ObservableCollection<USERS>(dataContext.USERS);
    LoginCommand = new RelayCommand(Login);
    Usernames = dataContext.USERS.ToList();
}
```

So my question is how do I display DEPARTMENTS title in the ComboBox? i've tried to set DisplayMemberPath property to 'DEPARTMENTS' or 'TITLE', but couldn't get the expecting result.

Comment: Doew User contain reference to its department?

Comment: Yes it does. It has DEPARTMENTS property which represents a referenced department (though it is null, I don't know why) and DEPARTMENTSReference entity reference

Comment: As a solution you can extract users from DB with their departments by calling Include("Departments"). Then you will be able to use DisplayMemberPAth or ItemTemplate. (I prefer the latter one though it requires more xaml-typing). By the way, be aware that when you set SelectedItem the search is performed among the available items (ItemsSource) and be default the equality of the references is checked.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works just as expected!